# Getting data from alternate dates of same ID column

Tags: t-sql

I've a table data as below, now I need to fetch the record with in same code, where (Value2-Value1)*2 of one row >= (Value2-Value1) of consequtive date row. (all dates are uniform with in all codes)

```
    ---------------------------------------
    code      Date      Value1      Value2
    ---------------------------------------
    1         1-1-2018   13          14
    1         2-1-2018   14          16
    1         4-1-2018   15          18
    2         1-1-2019    1           3
    2         2-1-2018    2           3
    2         4-1-2018    3           7
```

ex: output needs to be 
1 1-1-2018 13 14

as I am begginer to SQL coding, tried my best, but cannot get through with compare only on consequtive dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a self join.
You can specify all the conditions you've listed in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT T0.code, T0.Date, T0.Value1, T0.Value2
FROM Table As T0
JOIN Table As T1
ON T0.code = T1.code
AND T0.Date = DateAdd(Day, 1, T1.Date)
AND (T0.Value2 - T0.Value1) * 2 >= T1.Value2 - T1.Value1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked, I got confused at  comparing alternate dates

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: just one qq, if I want to apply another condition that for ex: only when the (value1 - value 2) of before the row  1 1-1-2018 13 14  is greater than 3 then only I need to get that output along with the original condiation. how can I apply

Comment: You can add a `where` clause to the query to hold that condition.

Comment: I've tried but no luck, but how can I put it in where clause if the conditions have to be previous day..

Comment: So now you want to compare the values of three different rows? if that's true, a simple self join is not going to help much. You could add one more join but that will be cumbersome as well as inefficient. In this case, you might be better of using a completely different technique - which is an overkill for the first, simpler question. I would suggest asking a new question for this scenario.

Comment: got it, I've raised new question as below, which will be my final task:  Thanks your time on this, really owe you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57823188/extract-data-by-comparing-4-different-rows