# Extract Data by comparing 4 different rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

The Table data is as below, need to extract records that met the below conditions

Here Value = Value2-Value1

```
    Value of two days back data should be > 2
    Value of last day  data is < 0
    Value of next day data is < 4 and >0
    Value of after next day data > 4
```

All the dates are weekdays,if any date falls on friday, need to compare with next day ie.. Monday. and comparision is with alternative days only

from below output have to be.

```
1         4-1-2018   15          18
2         3-1-2018    3           0 


    -----------------------------------
    code      Date      Value1      Value2
    ---------------------------------------
    1         1-1-2018   13          14
    1         2-1-2018   14          18
    1         3-1-2018   15          11
    1         4-1-2018   15          18
    1         5-1-2018   15          18
    1         6-1-2018   11          18
    1         7-1-2018   15          18
    2         1-1-2019    1           3
    2         2-1-2018    2           5
    2         3-1-2018    3           0
    2         4-1-2018    3           7
    2         5-1-2018    3           4
    2         6-1-2018    3           9
    2         7-1-2018    3           7
```

I am pretty much confused at comparing multiple rows, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please tell us the actual RDBMS (probably SQL-Server) and the version. If this is SQL-Server 2012+ you might read about LEAD and LAG together with the OVER clause

Comment: its sql server 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with v2012 we have [support for `LAG()` and `LEAD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/analytic-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Try this out:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(code INT,[Date] DATE,Value1 INT,Value2 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'1-1-2018',13,14)
,(1,'2-1-2018',14,18)
,(1,'3-1-2018',15,11)
,(1,'4-1-2018',15,18)
,(1,'5-1-2018',15,18)
,(1,'6-1-2018',11,18)
,(1,'7-1-2018',15,18)
,(2,'1-1-2019', 1, 3)
,(2,'2-1-2018', 2, 5)
,(2,'3-1-2018', 3, 0)
,(2,'4-1-2018', 3, 7)
,(2,'5-1-2018', 3, 4)
,(2,'6-1-2018', 3, 9)
,(2,'7-1-2018', 3, 7);


WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,LAG(Value2-Value1,2) OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY [Date]) TwoDaysBack
          ,LAG(Value2-Value1,1) OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY [Date]) Yesterday
          ,LEAD(Value2-Value1,1) OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY [Date]) tomorrow
          ,LEAD(Value2-Value1,2) OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY [Date]) TwoDaysAhead
    FROM @tbl 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

I do not really understand, how you want to use these values in a filter to get the expected output. If you need help with this, just come back...

The result

```
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| code | Date       | Value1 | Value2 | TwoDaysBack | Yesterday | tomorrow | TwoDaysAhead |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 1    | 2018-01-01 | 13     | 14     | NULL        | NULL      | 4        | -4           |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 1    | 2018-01-02 | 14     | 18     | NULL        | 1         | -4       | 3            |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 1    | 2018-01-03 | 15     | 11     | 1           | 4         | 3        | 3            |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 1    | 2018-01-04 | 15     | 18     | 4           | -4        | 3        | 7            |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 1    | 2018-01-05 | 15     | 18     | -4          | 3         | 7        | 3            |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 1    | 2018-01-06 | 11     | 18     | 3           | 3         | 3        | NULL         |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 1    | 2018-01-07 | 15     | 18     | 3           | 7         | NULL     | NULL         |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 2    | 2018-01-02 | 2      | 5      | NULL        | NULL      | -3       | 4            |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 2    | 2018-01-03 | 3      | 0      | NULL        | 3         | 4        | 1            |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 2    | 2018-01-04 | 3      | 7      | 3           | -3        | 1        | 6            |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 2    | 2018-01-05 | 3      | 4      | -3          | 4         | 6        | 4            |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 2    | 2018-01-06 | 3      | 9      | 4           | 1         | 4        | 2            |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 2    | 2018-01-07 | 3      | 7      | 1           | 6         | 2        | NULL         |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 2    | 2019-01-01 | 1      | 3      | 6           | 4         | NULL     | NULL         |
+------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

The idea in short:

Both, LAG() and LEAD() take an argument for the needed value, a second, how many rowswe want to skip, and as a third argument a default value you might specify to avoid NULLs in the result, when there is no row in scope.

The OVER() clause will tell any *windowing function* if we want to think of the set as divided in groups and the sort order (otherwise the system would not know what is *leading* or *lagging*.

Answer (score 2):

With [`lead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`lag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window functions:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    lag(value2 - value1, 2) over (partition by code order by date) prev2,
    lag(value2 - value1, 1) over (partition by code order by date) prev1,
    lead(value2 - value1, 1) over (partition by code order by date) next1,
    lead(value2 - value1, 2) over (partition by code order by date) next2
  from tablename
)
select code, date, value1, value2
from cte 
where prev2 > 2 and prev1 < 0 and next1 > 0 and next1 < 4 and next2 > 4
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=10c9fb9046912be7de60b5bf47e0cf87).
Results:

```
code | date                | value1 | value2
---: | :------------------ | -----: | -----:
   1 | 01/04/2018 00:00:00 |     15 |     18
   2 | 01/04/2018 00:00:00 |      3 |      7
```

There is a difference between your expected results for `code = 2` and my results, so check its validity.

Comment: Nice forpas, I need to make one as answer so Shnugo replied first, but yours is the output I need so upvoted.. Thanks for the help  forpas and Shnugo.... I am trying the solution will get back to you soon.